# AWK Print fields with new values if match, else print line

Tags: awk

I have two files - FileA and FileB. FileA will be changed.  FileB contains the new values.  FileB has 3 fields.  The first two fields will be compared with FileA's first two fields.  If the fields match, Field3 should be changed.   The code below is working in this manner:  "If the two values match, change field3 and print the line.  If there is no match, next."  The behavior I want is, "If there is no match, print the line unchanged."  The "else" part of the code is not working and I've tried so many variations.

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '
# first, read in data from file B
NR == FNR { values[$1 FS $2] = $3; next }

# then, output modified lines from matching lines in file A
($1 FS $2) in values { $3 = values[$1 FS $2]; print } else { print $0 }
' fileB fileA
```

FileA

```
PROVDSRJ02.RD.RI    ae0.0   16      
PROVDSRJ02.RD.RI    ae1.1   1000    
PROVDSRJ02.RD.RI    ae2.0   5000    
PROVDSRJ02.RD.RI    ae3.0   5000    
ASHBBBRJ01.RD.AS    ae39.0  16      
ASHBBPRJ01.RD.AS    ae2.0   16      
ASHBBPRJ02.RD.AS    ae1.0   16      
ASHBBPRJ02.RD.AS    ae2.0   16      
ASHBBBRJ01.RD.AS    ae0.0   16      
ASHBBBRJ01.RD.AS    ae11.0  16
```

FileB

```
ASHBBBRJ01.RD.AS    ae10.0  524
ASHBBBRJ01.RD.AS    ae11.0  235
ASHBBBRJ01.RD.AS    ae39.0  2096
ASHBBBRJ01.RD.AS    ae6.0   183
ASHBBBRJ01.RD.AS    ae7.0   1141
ASHBBBRJ02.RD.AS    ae11.0  88
ASHBBBRJ02.RD.AS    ae13.0  333
ASHBBBRJ02.RD.AS    ae20.0  374
ASHBBBRJ02.RD.AS    ae9.0   1885
```

Desired Output (** indicate changed lines and should not be included in code)

```
PROVDSRJ02.RD.RI    ae0.0   16      
PROVDSRJ02.RD.RI    ae1.1   1000    
PROVDSRJ02.RD.RI    ae2.0   5000    
PROVDSRJ02.RD.RI    ae3.0   5000    
**ASHBBBRJ01.RD.AS    ae39.0  2096**    
ASHBBPRJ01.RD.AS    ae2.0   16      
ASHBBPRJ02.RD.AS    ae1.0   16      
ASHBBPRJ02.RD.AS    ae2.0   16      
ASHBBBRJ01.RD.AS    ae0.0   16      
**ASHBBBRJ01.RD.AS    ae11.0  235**
```

Comment: Please, post sample of `FileA`and `FileB` along with the expected output. Thanks.

Comment: Please read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and adhere to it or risk being ignored

Comment: It is not a duplicate.  Somebody commented on that last post and said to create a new post...I'm just doing what I was told...

Comment: @user3746195: okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is off. Check the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info) for some learning resources.

In any case, you don't need an `else` as such. You can conditionally set `$3` to the new value (as you already are doing), and then always print the line (which may have been modified or not).

Here we use the shortcut `1` to always print the line. `1` is an always-true pattern that invokes the default action, which is to print the current line. If that doesn't make sense now, it will soon.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} 
       NR == FNR {values[$1 FS $2] = $3; next} 
       ($1 FS $2) in values {$3 = values[$1 FS $2]}1' fileB fileA
PROVDSRJ02.RD.RI    ae0.0   16
PROVDSRJ02.RD.RI    ae1.1   1000
PROVDSRJ02.RD.RI    ae2.0   5000
PROVDSRJ02.RD.RI    ae3.0   5000
ASHBBBRJ01.RD.AS    ae39.0  2096
ASHBBPRJ01.RD.AS    ae2.0   16
ASHBBPRJ02.RD.AS    ae1.0   16
ASHBBPRJ02.RD.AS    ae2.0   16
ASHBBBRJ01.RD.AS    ae0.0   16
ASHBBBRJ01.RD.AS    ae11.0  235
```

Comment: Consider setting`{idx=$1 FS $2}` just once up front and then use `idx` everywhere rather than hard-coding `$1 FS $2` in 3 places.